# How to reprocess image transforms that already exist in the database

Tags: image-transforms

If I import a Craft DB into my local db, and it has references to image transforms that existed in another environment, it won't recreate them in the filesystem when a page is loaded that asks for one of those transforms. Is there a way to tell Craft to recreate these transforms, or is the only option to retrieve the transforms from the other environment and bring them over?

I tried running `./craft index-assets/all` in the terminal but that didn't work. Not really sure what that command is meant for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `./craft clear-caches/transform-indexes` to clear your transform indexes.